# In vimscript, how can I highlight the whole text of the buffer when losing focus?

Tags: vim

In vimscript, I want to highlight the whole text when losing focus; the following command does not work but moves cursor one line below.

```
autocmd FocusLost * execute '/.'
```

Let me know the correct way.

---

I include my code with what @Ry- answered.

The code dims the whole text of the buffer when losing focus and reverts it in syntax highlight when gaining focus.

```
augroup dimbuf
  autocmd!
  autocmd FocusLost * execute 'highlight Search cterm=none guifg=#555555 guibg=NONE
  autocmd FocusLost * call matchadd('Search', '.', 0, 1843991912)
  autocmd FocusGained * call matchdelete(1843991912)
  autocmd FocusGained * execute 'highlight Search none' | execute 'highlight Search cterm=reverse'
augroup END
```

Comment: No need to add "solved" to the title. You indicate that your problem has been solved by accepting an answer (which you've done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `:help autocmd-searchpat`:

> Autocommands do not change the current search patterns. Vim saves the current search patterns before executing autocommands then restores them after the autocommands finish. This means that autocommands do not affect the strings highlighted with the 'hlsearch' option. Within autocommands, you can still use search patterns normally, e.g., with the `n` command.
>
> If you want an autocommand to set the search pattern, such that it is used after the autocommand finishes, use the `:let @/ =` command.
>
> The search-highlighting cannot be switched off with `:nohlsearch` in an autocommand. Use the 'h' flag in the 'shada' option to disable search-highlighting when starting Vim.

So, you can set the last search register directly:

```
autocmd FocusLost * let @/ = '.'
```

But if you’re looking for the visual effect, have you considered adding a match instead? It won’t clobber your last search.

```
augroup blur-highlight
  autocmd!
  autocmd FocusLost * call matchadd('Search', '.', 0, 1843991912) " random integer
  autocmd FocusGained * call matchdelete(1843991912)
augroup END
```

Comment: Hi Ry-, thank you for your answer. You suggested exactly what I wanted. I tried to dim the whole text in dark grey when losing focus and to revert it in syntax highlight when gaining focus. I included your suggestion in my code. It works perfectly.